# iTunes Smart Playlist - currently playing track

Tags: itunes, playlist

Is it possible to include the currently playing track in a smart playlist?

Ultimately, what I'm after is a smart playlist that includes tracks without a rating and tracks that I've already rated 3-5.  If I rate something 1 or 2, I want it to keep playing until the end of the song instead of just automatically kicking it out of the playlist and skipping to the next song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a two-step solution to this:

First create a smart playlist for tracks that are unrated or have 3-5 stars.

Second, set that playlist as the source for iTunes DJ, and play tracks using that. Last I checked, tracks would play through even if they wound up getting tagged in mid-play in a way that would remove them from the smart playlist.